# XSLT XML to CSV

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT and really hoping someone can help me out. I get an XML document from our server and I need to be able to convert this to a CSV file. Here is an example of the XML File:

```
<root>
  <DataRow>
    <ColumnName>Value</ColumnName>
    <ColumnName>Value</ColumnName>
    <ColumnName>Value</ColumnName>
    <ColumnName>Value</ColumnName>
    <ColumnName>Value</ColumnName>
  </DataRow>
  <DataRow>
    <ColumnName>Value</ColumnName>
    <ColumnName>Value</ColumnName>
    <ColumnName>Value</ColumnName>
    <ColumnName>Value</ColumnName>
    <ColumnName>Value</ColumnName>
  </DataRow>
  <DataRow>
    <ColumnName>Value</ColumnName>
    <ColumnName>Value</ColumnName>
    <ColumnName>Value</ColumnName>
    <ColumnName>Value</ColumnName>
    <ColumnName>Value</ColumnName>
  </DataRow>
</root>
```

I need to be able to convert the XML into a CSV but I am having a hard time creating the XSL Template file and hoping someone can help me. The First row should be the column names and the second row and beyond should be the values. Is this possible inside XSLT to create something like this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!! Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Can you hard-code the columns (i.e. are they always going to be the same column names?) or should the solution determine the column names by examining the XML file?

Comment: The solution should determine the column names by examining the XML File. This is where it gets difficult as the XML file has different column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">    
        <xsl:for-each select="/root/DataRow[1]/*">
            <xsl:if test="position()!=1">
                <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="root/DataRow">
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <xsl:if test="position()!=1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Try this stylesheet.  It uses a default template and a nested loop for the values.

Comment: Tested the above code with the sample xml provided, recieved a well formed CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Generically, you want something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<xsl:template match="root/DataRow">
  <xsl:if test="position() = 2">
          <xsl:for-each select="*">
      <xsl:if test="position() != 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'"/>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:for-each select="*">
    <xsl:if test="position() != 1">
      <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'"/>
</xsl:template>
```

So the first template is the column header row, verbatim, so the column names need to be there.  It would be determined automatically if I knew more about what they are.  If they aren't really all named "ColumnName", a real example would help a lot.

Comment: The solution should determine the column names by examining the XML File. This is where it gets difficult as the XML file has different column names.

Comment: Is there to be a separate output for each root/DataRow combination?  Or will there be the same set of columns for each DataRow block?  In other words, will the first row be an aggregation of all columns found in the total of all DataRows, or one set because all DataRows share a common column set?

Comment: The XML File will always contain the same column names however different XML files will have different Column Names. XML1.xml will have certain column names compared to XML2.xml will have different column names

Comment: I have edited my example.  The first template match now grabs each column's name from the first block of DataRow (since you suggest every block is the same, we'll just grab one).  The second then marches through every DataRow/* to grab values, which will be laid out in the same order as the prior column name grab.

Comment: I get a 'Position()' is an unknown XSLT function. error when I execute it

Comment: when referencing a specific row, using DataRow[1] should return the first row.  Shouldn't need to call a position function.

Comment: This puts everything into one column, what I need is it to be like this

ColumnName, ColumnName, ColumnName
Value, Value, Value

Comment: Updated again, a bit more condensed this time.